# Is there a way to copy-paste images into Tiki-Wiki pages?

Tags: tiki-wiki

I have a large number of existing MS Word documents I want to import into tiki-wiki, but some of these include images that don't carry over into the editor (including the WYSIWYG editor).

I'm looking for some plugin or setting that would allow me to copy-paste images into the tiki-wiki editor that automatically uploads images to the file gallery and insert the image in place. Converting the documents to HTML code is one solution I have found to retain the images and Word documents, but removes the ability to easily edit the wiki pages.

I have looked and cannot seem to find anything like this. In fact, many members of the wiki community seem to be against such a feature. Has anyone found a plugin or workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that's not a feature in Tiki currently, it would be great if it was (i'm surprised anyone seemed to be against it, we always welcome volunteers and sponsors if you're willing to code or commission it!)

We are planning to migrate to markdown over the next few versions, so maybe add this as a feature request as part of that? The planning page is here https://dev.tiki.org/WYSIWYG-and-Markdown